# How to add radiobutton to each cell in table layout

Tags: android

I want to add radiobuttons for every cell in given below table and get their position based on row and column, how to achieve it? Kindly share your views. Thanks in advance. I have commented the code where i was adding text to each cells, may be at the same place we can add radiobuttons

[image]

Below is working code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout rl;
    RadioGroup rg;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] row = { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG" };
        String[] column = { "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3", "Col 4", "Col 5", "Col 6" };
        int rl = row.length;
        int cl = column.length;

        Log.d("--", "R-Lenght--" + rl + "   " + "C-Lenght--" + cl);

        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        TableLayout tableLayout = createTableLayout(row, column, rl, cl);
        HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

        hsv.addView(tableLayout);
        sv.addView(hsv);
        setContentView(sv);

    }

    public void makeCellEmpty(TableLayout tableLayout, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // get row from table with rowIndex
        TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);

        // get cell from row with columnIndex
        TextView textView = (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(columnIndex);

        // make it black
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void setHeaderTitle(TableLayout tableLayout, int rowIndex,
            int columnIndex) {

        // get row from table with rowIndex
        TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);

        // get cell from row with columnIndex
        TextView textView = (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(columnIndex);

        textView.setText("Hello");
    }

    private TableLayout createTableLayout(String[] rv, String[] cv,
            int rowCount, int columnCount) {
        // 1) Create a tableLayout and its params
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        // 2) create tableRow params
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        tableRowParams.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
        tableRowParams.weight = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            // 3) create tableRow
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[10];
            rl=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
            rg=new RadioGroup(this);

            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                // 4) create textView
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                // textView.setText(String.valueOf(j));
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                String s1 = Integer.toString(i);
                String s2 = Integer.toString(j);
                String s3 = s1 + s2;
                int id = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                Log.d("TAG", "-___>" + id);




                if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                    textView.setText("0==0");
                } else if (i == 0) {
                    Log.d("TAAG", "set Column Headers");
                    textView.setText(cv[j - 1]);
                } else if (j == 0) {
                    Log.d("TAAG", "Set Row Headers");
                    textView.setText(rv[i - 1]);
                } else {
                    /*textView.setText("" + id);
                    // check id=23
                    if (id == 23) {
                        textView.setText("ID=23");

                    }*/


                    //Add Radiobuttons here
                }

                // 5) add textView to tableRow
                tableRow.addView(textView, tableRowParams);

            }

            // 6) add tableRow to tableLayout
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow, tableLayoutParams);
        }

        return tableLayout;
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use GridView.

Answer (score 0):

please use listview instead of table layout

```
   ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

 // values is a StringArray holding some string values.
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter (getActivity(), values);
listView.setAdapter(customAdapter );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multi-dimensional array of Radio Button or group or whatever you want...

```
RadioButton[][] rb = new RadioButton[][];
```

Use above statement for declaring it and for accessing it use two loops which are nested. One loop is nested in another.

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<=5;j++)
    {
         rb[i][j] = new RadioButton(this);
    }
}
```